# Qual è il significato di "comporre" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nelle note al canto XXI del *Paradiso* di Emilio Pasquini e Antonio Quaglio ho letto questa frase riferita a San Pietro Daminano (grassetto mio):

> Cardinale dal 1057 si adoperò a Roma per **comporre** lo scisma sorto in seguito al contrasto tra  papa Niccolò II e l'antipapa Benedetto X.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni della voce "comporre" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000425.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000426.jpg). Ho scelto questo questo vocabolario perché, di solito, è il più completo. Tuttavia, non sono sicura di essere riuscita a capire il senso della frase sopra citata: ci sta dicendo che Pietro Damiano fu uno dei macchinatori dello "scisma sorto in seguito al contrasto tra  papa Niccolò II e l'antipapa Benedetto X"? Cioè, che fece una serie di azioni a Roma con lo scopo di
produrre questo scisma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo caso è il significato numero 15 nel GDLI. Vale a dire

> **15** Mettere d'accordo, conciliare; riconciliare, pacificare

Come si può vedere dagli esempi lì presenti, è spesso usato nella forma "comporre un disaccordo" o "comporre un litigio". Questo significato è derivato metaforicamente dal più letterale significato 5 (unire, connettere).

Nel contesto, significa che san Pietro Damiano andò a Roma per trovare un accordo tra Niccolò II e Benedetto X, che aspiravano entrambi al soglio pontificio.